# How to calculate a probability density function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, statistics

Note In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224087/d3-js-how-to-add-distribution-curves-to-histograms-in-version-4), I asked how to add a distribution **line** to the chart.

This is my current status:
[image]

I don’t quite understand how to plot two distributions **curves** for the histograms. Like this: [image]

This is my code (using D3.js version 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    .bar1 rect {
      fill: rgba(0,0,255,0.6);
    }

    .bar1:hover rect{
      fill: rgba(0,0,255,0.9);
    }

    .bar1 text {
      fill: #fff;
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .bar2 rect {
      fill: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    }

    .bar2:hover rect{
      fill: rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
    }

    .bar2 text {
      fill: #fff;
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    function draw(data) {

      var allCongruentData = data.map(function(e){ return e.Congruent;});
      var allIncongruentData = data.map(function(e){ return e.Incongruent;});

      var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

      var svg = d3.select("svg"),
          margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
          width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .rangeRound([0, width])
          .domain([8, 36]);

      var bins1 = d3.histogram()
          .domain(x.domain())
          .thresholds(x.ticks(40))
          (allCongruentData);

      // var curve = d3.line()
      //       .x(function(d) { return ???; })
      //       .y(function(d) { return y(d.Congruent); })
      //       .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5));

      var bins2 = d3.histogram()
          .domain(x.domain())
          .thresholds(x.ticks(40))
          (allIncongruentData);

      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(bins1, function(d) { return d.length; })])
          .range([height, 0]);

      var bar1 = g.selectAll(".bar1")
        .data(bins1)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "bar1")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; });

      bar1.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 0.5)
          .attr("width", x(bins1[0].x1) - x(bins1[0].x0) - 1)
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });


      var bar2 = g.selectAll(".bar2")
        .data(bins2)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "bar2")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; });

      bar2.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 0.5)
          .attr("width", x(bins2[0].x1) - x(bins2[0].x0) - 1)
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });

      bar1.append("text")
          .attr("dy", ".75em") // why?
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("x", (x(bins1[0].x1) - x(bins1[0].x0)) / 2)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });

      bar2.append("text")
          .attr("dy", ".75em") // why?
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("x", (x(bins2[0].x1) - x(bins2[0].x0)) / 2)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });

      g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      var legend = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 245) + "," + 40 + ")")
              .selectAll("g")
              .data(["Congruent", "Incongruent"])
              .enter().append("g");

          legend.append("text")
              .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                  return i * 30 + 5;
              })
              .attr("x", 200)
              .text(function(d) {
                  return d;
              });

          legend.append("rect")
              .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                  return i * 30 - 8;
              })
              .attr("x", 167)
              .attr("width", 20)
              .attr("height", 20)
              .attr("fill", function(d) {
                  if (d == "Congruent") {
                      return 'rgba(0,0,255,0.6';
                  } else {
                      return 'rgba(255,0,0,0.6';
                  }
              });

      // g.append("path")
      //     .datum(data)
      //     .attr("d", line);

    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Stroop Test</h1>
    <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      d3.csv("stroopdata.csv", function(d) {
          d.Congruent = +d.Congruent;
          d.Incongruent = +d.Incongruent;
          return d;
        }, draw);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The data looks like this:

```
Congruent,Incongruent
12.079,19.278
16.791,18.741
9.564,21.214
8.630,15.687
14.669,22.803
12.238,20.878
14.692,24.572
8.987,17.394
9.401,20.762
14.480,26.282
22.328,24.524
15.298,18.644
15.073,17.510
16.929,20.330
18.200,35.255
12.130,22.158
18.495,25.139
10.639,20.429
11.344,17.425
12.369,34.288
12.944,23.894
14.233,17.960
19.710,22.058
16.004,21.157
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This question has (almost) nothing to do with D3. It's very easy for D3 to plot the line, once you have the data. The real title of this question should be: *"How to calculate a probability density function in JavaScript"*. Have in mind that a PDF is not exactly the same of a Gaussian curve.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Ok, I thought D3 might have a automagic function to calculate and plot it. I change the question.

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't. I believe you'll have to look for a statistic js library, or create your own function. However, d3 can calculate the mean, the median, the variance and the standard deviation... those are good starters to create your line.

Comment: Alright, thank you. If you have any recommendations or experiences which .js-library is the best suited for a simple pdf let us know :)

Comment: I just found this using google (I didn't test it), it may help: https://github.com/errcw/gaussian